# Can "runtime" be used for something outside a computer programming context?

Tags: word-usage

The word "runtime" appears in contexts related to computer programmes as a noun for the time when a programme or part of it is executed. So far, so good.

May I, however, use the word also in other contexts not related to computer programming? May I use it e.g. as a shorter way to say "the period of time when Project XYZ is being implemented", as in:

> During project runtime, the steering committee will meet at least biweekly.
>
> Project runtime is from May 2017 to June 2018.

Or am I restricted to expressions such as

> The project will be implemented between May 2017 and June 2018.
>
> During project implementation, the steering committee will meet regularly, at least biweekly.

Other suggestions to express stuff like that elegantly are welcome.

Regaring "runtime": I looked it up in various dictionaires and text corpora, but so far I found it used only in the programming context. My desire to use it elsewhere may be rooted in my German background, as German *Laufzeit* can well be used for projects, cultural programmes, and funding programmes, too.

Comment: You can use "runtime" in the context of anything that starts to run, runs and stops running - such as a computer program being executed or a film being screened. These terms are not applicable to a project (you cannot put your ear next to a project and say "I hear it running now").

Comment: Michael: thanks. However, I somehow have a problem understanding your logic. Okay, I cannot "hear" a project running, but likewise I cannot hear a computer programme running; and if we look at secondary indicators, yes, I can see e.g. characters dancing on the computer screen, but I also can see people rushing through the corridors working on my project; so again, using your logic I could use "runtime" for my project anyway. Likewise, a project can be started, be stopped and be restarted. Or is my thinking twisted? - Anyway, a clear "No, not suitable for projects" would suffice.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You can if that's a project , that is ran by my company. I see your point there, but it can be metaphorical perhaps.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Are people rushing through the corridors constantly, day and night, for two months?

Comment: You can probably even use it to refer to how long it takes someone to complete a marathon.

Comment: @Michael, regarding constantly occupied corridors in my hypothetical project: if people are working in shifts, why not?

Comment: Well, it depends on the nature of your project. I was going to say you must have some kind of an engine running in order to have a runtime, but a theatre rehearsal qualifies too in my book. So let me say you must have something that has a distinct ON **mode**. I cannot come up with an example of a long-term project of such nature. A military operation - perhaps. But you wouldn't say "during the runtime of the Six-Day War".

Comment: As matter of joke I think you can use runtime. Don't forget to precise we are not machines.

Comment: @Michael: oh, thanks, I think now I do understand your underlying concept. Yes, seen in this light, my projects do not have "on" mode and "off" mode. Like a human being: true it "starts" at a moment and "ends" at a moment, but you cannot switch it on and off ad libitum (so far, at least). Which inspires the next question: may I speak of a **project lifetime**?

Comment: Yes, I think *project lifetime* would be understood and quite idiomatic - and there are 8,790 Google Books results to support this. But "*the course of the project*" would be more idiomatic (1,880,000 results).

Answer (score 2):

[Absolutely](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/runtime):

> 1. The time that a film or DVD lasts.
>
>    *‘a thriller that is so well paced it seems a lot shorter than its three-hour runtime’*

Also:

> The length of time a program takes to run.